# Cannot open display error with WSL2

Tags: ubuntu, wsl2

I had WSl installed and updated it according to this [MS guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/tutorials/gui-apps):

```
wsl --update
wsl --shutdown
```

and tried to run gedit:

```
sudo apt install gedit -y
gedit ~/.bashrc
```

but got

```
(gedit:1854): Gtk-WARNING **: 19:49:45.422: cannot open display:
```

and the same with gimp and other graphical apps.

Should I do some further manipulations like installing ubuntu desktop like

```
apt install gnome
```

or using VcXsrc or opening a port in Windows Firewall?

WSL version:

```
WSL version: 1.2.0.0
Kernel version: 5.15.90.1
WSLg version: 1.0.51
MSRDC version: 1.2.3770
Direct3D version: 1.608.2-61064218
DXCore version: 10.0.25131.1002-220531-1700.rs-onecore-base2-hyp
Windows version: 10.0.19045.2604
```

The command

```
wsl --list --online
```

outputs the following:

```
The following is a list of valid distributions that can be installed.
Install using 'wsl.exe --install <Distro>'.

NAME                                   FRIENDLY NAME
Ubuntu                                 Ubuntu
Debian                                 Debian GNU/Linux
kali-linux                             Kali Linux Rolling
Ubuntu-18.04                           Ubuntu 18.04 LTS
Ubuntu-20.04                           Ubuntu 20.04 LTS
Ubuntu-22.04                           Ubuntu 22.04 LTS
OracleLinux_8_5                        Oracle Linux 8.5
OracleLinux_7_9                        Oracle Linux 7.9
SUSE-Linux-Enterprise-Server-15-SP4    SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 15 SP4
openSUSE-Leap-15.4                     openSUSE Leap 15.4
openSUSE-Tumbleweed                    openSUSE Tumbleweed
```

Comment: @Ramhound I do not know. What is the command to start it?

Comment: @Ramhound see updated post

Comment: @Ramhound I am using Ubuntu-22.04. I did not do `wsl --install` because I thought that I already have WSL installed, and it is not clear for me what does `Install using 'wsl.exe --install <Distro>'` message mean. Actually Ubuntu-22.04 is installed and I am using it in terminal (as the app from MS Store)

Comment: @Ramhound restarting the machine did not help. Should I do something like "wsl --install ..."?

Comment: @Ramhound It seems that you are confusing `wsl --list --verbose` with `wsl --list --online`.  The purpose of `wsl --list --online`' is to show the distribution that *can* be installed.  I think you mean to ask for `wsl -l -v` to determine the distribution that is installed.

Comment: @Dmitriano Can you add the output of `echo $DISPLAY` to your question?  I'm assuming that `wsl -l -v` correctly shows that you are running Ubuntu-22.04, right? ;-)

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds `$DISPLAY` is empty, `wsl -l -v` shows `Ubuntu-22.04    Running  1` where 1 is VERSION.

Comment: @Dmitriano Ah, there you go - WSLg only works with WSL2.

Comment: Try `wsl --set-version Ubuntu-22.04 2` - Does it convert or give an error?

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds Started `wsl --set-version Ubuntu-22.04`, the conversion took probably a hour or two but finally succeeded and I was able to run `gedit`